# How to refresh cache of a microservice for any CRUD operation performed on DB from another microservice

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, microservices

I have 2 microservices, A and B and a postgres database. Microservice B directly interacts with database to perform CRUD operations. From microservice A, while starting up application, we are caching all database records. Now for any update/insert in db using Microservice B should also update cache in Microservice A.

Currently we are using time-based cache refresh i.e., updating caching in Microservice A for every 1 hour.

Please suggest better approach or any cache mechanisms that handle this..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check if Micro service A can somehow be notified if there is some change in the database. Listen to the notification and if any, refresh the cache

Comment: Thanks @abj1305. I enabled a rest endpoint at Microservice A and making a rest call from Microservice B to update cache at 'A'. I am looking if any of proven cache mechanism handle these or any even better approach we can..

Comment: You may find this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/communicating-between-microservices) useful.